# can't include *.axml file in another *.axml file

Tags: android-layout, xamarin.android

I want to include a layout of `.axml` file in another `.axml` using xamarin android but, 
when i use `<include>`  it doesn't show any thing. What is the equivalent to `<include>` of android  in mono android just like the link below:

[android reuse layouts](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no difference between Xamarin.Android (Mono for Android) or native Android's XML files. The `axml` extension is purely to trigger the code completion in VS and Xamarin Studio. Android does not care what extension the files have.

So let me allow to show a sample showing both the `<merge>` and `<include>` tags:

**progress_with_text.axml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <TextView 
    android:text="Loading..."
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/lblLoading" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="240dp"/>
  <ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/progBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="230dp"/>
</merge>
```

**main.axml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/progress_with_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This works perfectly fine!

Comment: What does the <merge> tag do? Do I need include it for any reusable component?