# Inheritance in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, inheritance

I use Xamarin for Android. I have two activities with some content, there is `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` and `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` in XML files.

In MainActivity I use two object for content control. These are `DrawerLayout` and `NavigationView`. To switch between activities I use own method.

```
private void OnNavigationItemSelected(object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
        {
            case (Resource.Id.home):
                //Go home

                break;

            case (Resource.Id.settings):
                //Go to other activity
                break;
        }

        drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
    }
```

`DrawerLayout`, `NavigationView` and `OnNavigationItemSelected` is located in MainActivity, but I've created one more activities. This is `Settings` and when I chose settings item, I'm moving to `Settings` activity.

I wrote the same implementation in `Settings` activity. I have `DrawerLayout`, `NavigationView` and `OnNavigationItemSelected`.

It turns out that I just copied code. Maybe I should use inheritance? I just don't understand how can I realize that in Android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the common layout.xml for share between each activities .

1. Put `DrawerLayout` and `NavigationView` into a xml we call it `A.xml`.
2. Include `A.xml` into the xml of home and settings.

#### Example

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include
        layout="@layout/A"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/17133102/8187800